# Change Block's Dimensions and Layout in Drupal 7 Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a jumbotron with some content inside of it. I want to set the dimensions and do other design elements on the block. But all I have in my template in the jumbotron div sections is:

How do I access the block in  that jumbotron region? And use bootstrap 3 rows and cols on it?

Comment: '<?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?>' this is the code that i meant to have there.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your blocks in /admin/structure/block

But that template file you probably don't need to touch, all it is doing is rendering the 'highlighted' section. Instead look at the HTML output generated from it and style it using CSS... in your theme or module. Am I missing something?

Comment: the block is populated with a php script theres no css so i guess i can just add classes and divs to the php. But will bootstrap 3 recognize its own col and row classes or does that have to be within the theme's files.